# Density points outside of a non-measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $\lambda$ be a Radon outer measure over $R^n$ (that is: all Borel sets are $\lambda$-measurable in Caratheodory sense, for every set $C$ there exists a Borel set $B$, $C \subset B$ such that $\lambda(C) = \lambda(B)$ and $\lambda$ is finite on compact sets) and let $A \subset R^n$.
Show that if $\lim \limits_{r \to 0}$ $\frac{\lambda(A \cap B(x,r))}{\lambda(B(x,r))} = 0$ for $\lambda$-almost every $x \in R^n\setminus A$ then $A$ is a $\lambda$ measurable set.
$B(x,r)$ is an open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$.
I tried using Lebesgue differentiation theorem for some indicator functions and outer regularity of the measure, but it doesn't seeem to work. Maybe some covering theorem could work?
I'm stuck, please help.

Comment: Let $C_S$ be the set of compact subsets of $S.$ If $S$ is $\lambda$-measurable, can we assume that $\lambda (S)=\sup \{\lambda(T):T\in C_S\}$?

Comment: yes, that's the Radon part

Comment: So I found the solution. Roughly, you prove that for any set (measurable or not) $A$ $\mu$-alomst all points in $A$ are of density $1$. Then you take any set $Z$ and prove the Caratheodory's criterion, that is $\mu(A \cap Z)+\mu(Z-A) \geq \mu(Z)$. You do it by taking open $U$, $Z \subset U$ and $\mu(U)$ approximates $\mu(Z)$. Then you cover $Z \cap A$ with disjoint balls $B$ such that their sum is a subset of $U$, and measure of this sum is equal to $\mu(U)$ (it's a non-trivial consequence of Bosecovitch covering theorem, look it up in the book), and

Comment: $\mu(A \cap Z \cap B) + \mu((Z-A) \cap B) > (1 + \epsilon) \mu(B)$ (this is from the asumptions and from the first observation from my previous answer above). It's pretty easy to finish the proof now. There was one mistake above, the sum of the balls $S$ is not equal in measure to $U$ but instead $\mu(Z \cap U - S) = 0$. Now everything should work fine.

Comment: If we can get this question reopened, you can post your comments as an answer.